# How to use the open activity, when pressing on pendingIntent in nottification

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have nottification in the left corner that opens my app. It works fine. Problem is that every time that user presses on nottification it creates apps in memory again, but not close the old one.

Certainly, I can hide nottification icon after the first touch, but I don't want.

Is there any way to use the same app that is already open?

Here is the service that creates this nottification:

```
 public class MyShippingService extends Service {

 NotificationManager nm;
  String LOG_TAG;
  int shortDate;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  }

  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       shortDate=intent.getIntExtra("shortDate", 1);
       sendNotif();
       return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  void sendNotif() {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Main.class);
      intent1.setAction("hello");
    intent1.putExtra("notification", true);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.nottification))
         .setTicker(getString(R.string.nottification))
         .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_icon)
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();

    nm.cancel(shortDate);
    nm.notify(shortDate, notify);
  }

  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest set the launch mode of the main activity to `singleTop`. Take a look to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). When you launch your activity again the intent will be received on the `onNewIntent()` method

Comment: Thanks, it works)  singleTop open the same activity when I click on nottification. But when activity already opened, not from nottification, but from desktop, and I click at the nottification, i get two version: one from nottification, and one from the desktop. Is there any way to close old version in this case?